What do the current Starships look like inside?
I suppose that not even a large part of the interior of the Starships for IFT-3 and IFT-4 looked like on this design map. So if you opened the hatch, what would you find inside the prototypes SpaceX is testing now? Is it just empty rooms? Are they even pressurized? Would you theoretically (without considering the g-forces, shaking and stuff) have been able to survive the entire IFT-4 flight onboard?

It's a hollow tube.
The IFT Starship diagram shown in the FAA's environmental assessment shows no crew compartments whatsoever:

This is basically the "cargo" variant of the Starship. The plan is to replace the payload region with crew compartments for the Crewed Starship, or with extra tankage for the Tanker variant. (And supposedly there will be a slightly different cargo variant for starlink deployments, replacing the full cargo door with an integrated starlink dispenser.)
The IFT-3 flight also included some internal cameras pointing at the cargo door, which helpfully showed how empty the interior was.

I would not expect them to start spending the money to add internal components until they get their launch, reentry, and recovery process working consistently.

the internal cameras also showed that IFT-3 was at least partially pressurised, there was a visible escape of atmosphere when the pez door opened

I wouldn't call that 'pressurized' as much as just 'airtight'. As far as I can tell, it was just the air that was in there when they closed the door (or whatever portion of it hadn't leaked out, it didn't seem to be at full ground pressure, though it's really hard to judge that from a webcam).

DarthPseudonym - I think that's probably correct that it wasn't pressurized, probably more like when they open the hatch on the depressurized airlock on ISS and the thermal cover flops over because of residual air rushing out.
